# Using a promise to return the lambda handler function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am using aws-serverless-express for my lambda handler along the lines of the following:

`const app = express();
const server = createServer(app, null);
export const app = (event, context) => proxy(server, event, context);`

This works all well and good but I would like to perform some async operations before exporting the app in the last line.

I thought I could return a promise instead that would resolve the proxy when all my operations completed but this doesn't appear to work.

Is there any way to delay exporting the handler until some async code completes?

**updated**

I did get this working although I haven't worked with lambda for sometime so there there might now be an alternative solution. What I did at the time that worked looks like the following

```js
import * as Promise from 'bluebird';
import {Callback, Context, Handler} from 'aws-lambda';
import {createServer, proxy} from 'aws-serverless-express';
import {eventContext} from 'aws-serverless-express/middleware';
import {Application} from 'express';
import {ServerlessApp} from './common/serverless-express-app';
import {startComponents} from './startup';

import * as http from 'http';

const INSTANCE = new ServerlessApp(startComponents());
const getServer = INSTANCE.initCompletePromise
.then((serverLessApp: Application) => {
    serverLessApp.use(eventContext());
    return createServer(serverLessApp);
});

const apiGWExpressApp: Handler = (event: any, context: Context, callback: 
  Callback) => {
  // context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  getServer
    .then((server: http.Server) => {
        proxy(server, event, context);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        CommonHelper.doHandlerCallback(() => {
            INSTANCE.logger.error('ERROR: ', error);
            context.fail(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    });
};

export {
   apiGWExpressApp
};
```

The gist of it is that my custom `ServerlessApp` would do various setup steps based on what was provided in the constructor within a promise that was made publicly available  e.g.

```js
export class ServerlessApp {
    private _initCompletePromise: Promise<express.Application>;
    private _app: express.Application;
    constructor(startComponents: StartComponent[]) {
        this._app = express();

       this._initCompletePromise = 
           new Promise<express.Application>((resolve, reject) => { 
               ...
               resolve(this._app);
           }
    }
    public get initCompletePromise(): Promise<express.Application> {
        return this._initCompletePromise;
    }
}
```

This way I was able to defer the main `createServer` call in the handler method until I was able to do all my initialization setup.

Comment: Could you solve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Jose see the update added to the question

Comment: Thanks @sam. I found a solution for what I needed. I use [serverless](http://serverless.com) to create the callback function. I just had to wrap it up

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into this issue. Perhaps you've solved it by now. For me it was the cold starts, I wanted to have my app fully initialized before it starts handling requests but asynchronously loading or reloading the aws-serverless module did not work. Instead I defined a default route in my app.js/main js file and that route is execute before all other routes in the system. I pass a next() parameter to it, and on my initial load it delays hitting next till its finished, so all requests responses in my application are with held till the system is loaded.

**Inside my app.js**

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  systemService.initSystemConfiguration().then(() => {
    next()
  })
})
```

**system.services.js**

```
module.exports.initSystemConfiguration = function() {
if(systemInitialized) {
     return Promise.resolve(true)
}
return longComputationReturningPromise()
```